# What code design is most efficient for working with large (relatively static) data grids?

Tags: asp.net

I plan to use asp.net to show about 2 million rows of data (about 7 columns) on the main index of the site in a data grid using jquery.  I only need to update the database once in a while, probably daily, so I wondered what would be the most efficient code design to reduce load if there are a large number of users (thinking there might be an efficient way to do it specifically for static data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I plan to use asp.net to show about 2 million rows of data (about 7 columns) on the main index of the site in a data grid using jquery.

Given that I don't know your domain, my suggestion would try to page it and example 1000 rows at a time because I cannot see user seeing all 2 million rows at one time

Else get only the records just required of the user, for the user, by the user

Comment: Hi, I am not worried about disrupting the service during updates, I am concerned with the time to fetch the data from the database if 2million rows of data are requested at once by too many users.

Comment: @user1166981 I would apply the same rule even for fetching the data, get when you have very less users on you database or website

Comment: The grid is to be displayed to each user at the instant they go to the webpage though. How do you mean?

Comment: @user1166981 every user does not to see 2 million records is that correct ? If yes that get only records that user request for or the records that are just for him

Comment: I need to find out if I can still do the filtering of the grid if it is not fully (pre)populated. I am going to use this grid: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/controls/examples/integration/gridandcombo/defaultcs.aspx?product=grid

Comment: @user1166981 tell me more what sort filtering are you after

Comment: like that demo, you just type the name into the box and it filters out the results

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14246/discussion-between-hatsoft-and-user1166981)